# Nginx auth_request handle saml 302 redirects

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy

I am using Nginx as a reverse proxy. Also, I am using auth_request feature to protect my resources. For that, auth_request always goes through authrization server where I am using SAML authentication. While authenticating, there is a redirect 302 to IDP (ssocircle in this case) which I am trying to follow at Nginx but I am always ending up with below error:

> no resolver defined to resolve idp.ssocircle.com while sending to
>   client, client: 127.0.0.1, server: , request: "GET / HTTP/1.1",
>   subrequest: "/saml/login", host: "localhost:9000"
>   *1269 auth request unexpected status: 502 while sending to client, client: 127.0.0.1,  server: , request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host:
>   "localhost:9000"

Here is my Nginx configuration:

```
server{
    listen 9000 ;

    auth_request /saml/login;
    proxy_intercept_errors on;
    error_page 301 302 307 = @handle_redirects ;

    location /saml/login {
        resolver 46.4.112.4 valid=300s;
        internal;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_pass_request_body off;
        proxy_set_header Content-Length "";

        proxy_pass http://localhost:9090/ ; # url to authorization server

    }

    location @handle_redirects {
        set $saved_redirect_location '$upstream_http_location';
        proxy_pass $saved_redirect_location;

    }

    location / {
        root data/www;
    }
    location /images/ {
        root data/ ;
    }
}
```

I tried adding the `resolver 46.4.112.4` IP of ssocircle but it didn't work.
Basically, I want to follow the redirect from my authorization server and have user to authenticate themselves at the IDP and return back to the original URL.
I am very new to Nginx. Any help will be much appreciated.

**Edit** : I am able to resolve the issue stated above. Restarting the Nginx worked for me. But again I am getting this error:

> auth request unexpected status: 302 while sending to client,

Comment: I'm stuck here too. Not sure how to handle the 302 or follow it to process data and return a 200. Have you made any progress?

Comment: @farhany - We changed our logic a bit. Use auth_request to intercept request to your protected resources. In your interception logic, check, If caller has the appropriate token or session then return 200 and caller will be able to access the protected resources. Else, return 401 and let your application trigger SAML authentication with sso provider.

Comment: are you doing the redirect to the IdP or a POST?

Comment: When we get 401, we started with POST request to IDP. Follow this document http://docs.oasis-open.org/security/saml/Post2.0/sstc-saml-tech-overview-2.0.html. We used  SP-Initiated SSO: POST/Artifact Bindings. Also if you are using Spring, then have a look at https://github.com/vdenotaris/spring-boot-security-saml-sample. Hope this helps.